# From compose to swarm : Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet'

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, telnet, docker-swarm

I have a docker-compose file that allows me to start and access a web application, this with the compose command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d` on the original `docker-compose-dev.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  learnintouch-startup:
    image: localhost:5000/learnintouch-startup
    container_name: learnintouch-startup
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/bin/learnintouch/engine"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.thalasoft/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/thalasoft.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.folkuniversitet/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet/account/data"
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - nodejs-learnintouch
  nodejs-learnintouch:
    image: localhost:5000/nodejs-learnintouch
    container_name: nodejs-learnintouch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/bin/learnintouch/engine"
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    links:
      - redis
  mysql:
    image: localhost:5000/mysql:5.6.30
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data"
  redis:
    image: localhost:5000/redis:3.0.7
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
```

Now, I'd like to run it in swarm mode instead. I understand swarm mode is available since I'm running docker version `17.05.0-ce` both for the engine and the client. The host is `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I could init the swarm all right with the `docker swarm init` command.

Then I try to start the web application:

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-swarm-dev.yml learnintouch
Creating network learnintouch_default
Creating service learnintouch_mysql
Creating service learnintouch_redis
Creating service learnintouch_learnintouch-startup
Creating service learnintouch_nodejs-learnintouch
```

The `learnintouch-startup` container has a MySQL client is trying to access the MySQL server in the `mysql` container.

But there is no such container name and therefore no such hostname any longer.

When, before, in non swarm mode, the container name was being used as the hostname, now, there is no such container name.

I tried with the following `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-swarm-dev.yml learnintouch` command on the `docker-compose-swarm-dev.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  learnintouch-startup:
    image: localhost:5000/learnintouch-startup
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/bin/learnintouch/engine"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.thalasoft/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/thalasoft.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.folkuniversitet/account/data:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet/account/data"
    ports:
      - "81:80"
  nodejs-learnintouch:
    image: localhost:5000/nodejs-learnintouch
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/bin/learnintouch/engine"
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
  mysql:
    image: localhost:5000/mysql:5.6.30
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data"
    hostname: mysql
  redis:
    image: localhost:5000/redis:3.0.7
```

How can I specify the hostname of a swarm service ?

Note that if I start the application in non swarm mode with the `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d` command then the application responds fine. It is only if I start it in swarm mode with the `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-swarm-dev.yml learnintouch` command that the `mysql` hostname is not found any longer: `The data source for the database db_learnintouch could not be initialized for the user learnintouch on the host mysql:3306`. Indeed, in that latter case, the container name is `learnintouch_mysql.1.pu846rr8to5gwxwnxpdm4hdth` instead of being `mysql`.

UPDATE: It appears the issue is not a hostname one but a swarm/mysql one. 
In the `mysql` container I can log in to MySQL just fine:

```
$ docker exec -it learnintouch_mysql.1.m51o8deg8cslb8mzayp119m67 bash
root@mysql:/usr/bin/mysql-5.6.30# cd /usr/bin/mysql/install;
root@mysql:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

But in the `learnintouch-startup` client container, I can only ping the `mysql` service but not log into it:

```
$ docker exec -it learnintouch_learnintouch-startup.1.kf13qktlvxs9rgjzaea2xxd68 bash
root@aa0f0539ba52:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet# cd /usr/bin/mysql/install 
root@aa0f0539ba52:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@aa0f0539ba52:/usr/bin/mysql/install# ping mysql
PING mysql (10.0.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
^C
--- mysql ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
```

I can also telnet in fact:

```
root@861cc3861e67:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet# telnet mysql 3306
Trying 10.0.0.6...
Connected to mysql.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.6.30-logs5L\i|Sj��=0t}62:k,8s]mysql_native_password

!#08S01Got packets out of orderConnection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm using a custom built MySQL version mysql:5.6.30 with the `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 # Allow client binding from any IP address instead of just 127.0.0.1
port            = 3306
sql_mode        = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION # This is strict mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
socket          = /usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
user            = root
basedir         = /usr/bin/mysql/install
datadir         = /usr/bin/mysql/install/data
log-bin         = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.bin.log
log-error       = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.error.log
general-log-file     = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.log
slow-query-log-file  = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.slow.queries.log
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
connect_timeout = 60
wait_timeout = 28800 # amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection
interactive_timeout = 28800 # same, but for interactive sessions
[client]
socket = /usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
protocol = tcp # Forces the client to use the TCP protocol, except for PHP which ignores it
```

There are no `/etc/hosts.allow` nor `/etc/hosts.deny` files in the `mysql` container.

There is no firewall around.

The Docker version is 17.05.0-ce on both engine and client and the docker-compose version is 1.16.1.

UPDATE: After deleting the swarm and starting it again, I could run the application in the browser and see it run just fine. And so, following this, I did another delete followed by a start, and again, the same error occured. So the error, sometimes, but rarely, does not occur.

UPDATE: It appears, running the `telnet mysql 3306` command from within the client container, removes the issue and allows the MySQL client connection to proceed. This is consistent: I delete the swarm and start it anew, I open a bash in the client container, I try to log in the MySQL server container and it fails, I retry many times and it fails all the same, I run the `ping mysql` command and then try again to connect many times and it fails, and I then run the `telnet mysql 3306` command and try then to connect and it succeeds.

```
root@2651380ce02e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# cd /usr/bin/mysql/install; bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@2651380ce02e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# 
root@2651380ce02e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# ping mysql
PING mysql (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
^C
--- mysql ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.088/0.096/0.109/0.009 ms
root@2651380ce02e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# telnet mysql 3306
Trying 10.0.0.4...
Connected to mysql.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.6.30-logf[tT)mlX��Pi@EwHCT\SkBmysql_native_password
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@2651380ce02e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# cd /usr/bin/mysql/install; bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

Here is a complete demo run as evidence:

```
$ docker exec -it learnintouch_learnintouch-startup.1.ili3m1kre9q2eaiyzlucr2uot bash
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet# cd /usr/bin/mysql/install; bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -pEnter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# 
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# 
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# ping mysql
PING mysql (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.110 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
^C
--- mysql ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.083/0.110/0.027 ms
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# ping mysql
PING mysql (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
^C
--- mysql ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.082/0.092/0.105/0.014 ms
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# telnet mysql 3306
Trying 10.0.0.4...
Connected to mysql.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.6.30-logZo?*R@)M��(~cWg"q5R}?amysql_native_password
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.30-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> quit;
Bye
root@ce21d5b78886:/usr/bin/mysql/install#
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the service name which you have specified in docker-compose file as the hostname in swarm, for example you have your mysql service name as `mysql` you can use that name as hostname,moreover some options like links are not supported in docker stack https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#not-supported-for-docker-stack-deploy

in case you want to use different hostname in different network,then you can use aliases
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks

Comment: How come the `docker ps` command then shows a different randomized container name for my MySQL service ? I need to have a hostname of `mysql` and therefore I suppose I need to have a container name of `mysql` as well. I added a paragraph to my question.

Comment: when you deploy it in stack the containers are runned by services hence the services deploy containers with their known container_name,incase when you scale a particular service by 3 , the service will deploy 3 containers under it control,so any interaction to the scaled containers can only be done using the service name

Comment: So how can I have my MySQL service being exposed under the hostname `mysql` ? That is the title of my question :-)

Comment: yeah,since you have the service name as mysql in docker-compose file
get into a container launced by nodejs-learnintouch service and enter `ping mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I suspected a bug in this `mysql:5.6.30` and so I removed and replaced it with `mariadb:10.1.24` and the issue was gone.